# Produce two plots with the same plotOutput() in a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I have the `shiny` app below in which the user select which plots he wants to display. The issue is that if for example only `mtcars` is selected I want it to be displayed on top and if then `iris` is selected the `mtcars` plot will be displayed under `iris` plot. This is why Im trying to produse them using the same `plotOutput()`. Otherwise when `mtcars` would be the only selection ther would be an empty space over it.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
    header = dashboardHeader(title = "My dashboard"),
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(
        uiOutput("dbs")

    ),
    body = dashboardBody(
        plotOutput("fn")
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {



    output$dbs<-renderUI({

            pickerInput("DB", "Select Database/s", 
                        choices = c("iris","mtcars"), 
                        multiple = T,options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE),
                        selected = "iris")

    })
    output$fn<-renderPlot({
        if(input$DB=="iris"){
            plot(iris) 
        }
        else if(input$DB=="mtcars"){
            plot(mtcars)
        }
        else if(input$DB==c("iris","mtcars")){
            plot(iris) 
            plot(mtcars)
        }



    })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: That is not possible in shiny, either duplicate your code, or work with modules

Comment: Basically I want to always have a plot on top. Maybe I could achieve it with another way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

an approach

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- dashboardPage(
    header = dashboardHeader(title = "My dashboard"),
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(
        uiOutput("dbs")

    ),
    body = dashboardBody(
        plotOutput("fn"),
        plotOutput("fn2")
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {



    output$dbs<-renderUI({

            pickerInput("DB", "Select Database/s", 
                        choices = c("iris","mtcars"), 
                        multiple = T,options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE),
                        selected = "iris")

    })
    output$fn<-renderPlot({
        if("iris" %in% input$DB & "mtcars" %in% input$DB){
            plot(iris)

        }
        else if("iris" %in% input$DB){
            plot(iris) 
        }
        else if("mtcars" %in% input$DB){
            plot(mtcars)
        }



    })
    output$fn2<-renderPlot({
        if("iris" %in% input$DB & "mtcars" %in% input$DB){
            plot(mtcars)

        }
        else if("iris" %in% input$DB){
            return(NULL) 
        }
        else if("mtcars" %in% input$DB){
            return(NULL)
        }



    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```